# Is there an upper bound for this product over primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

numberFix a positve real number $X\geq 1$ large enough. Is there an upper bound for this product $$\prod_{y<p\leq X}\left(1+\frac{260}{p}+\sum_{\nu \geq 2} \frac{1}{p^{25\nu/32}}\right)$$
in terms of $\log(X)$ and $\log(y)$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: by looking at the $\log$ you can deduce it from the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) : $\sum_{\alpha x < p < x} \frac{1}{p} \sim \int_{\alpha x}^x \frac{1}{t} \frac{dt}{\ln t}$ when $x \to \infty$ and $\alpha$ is a constant. but when you consider say $y = x-\sqrt{x}$ it is much more complicated, and it is related to the [prime gap problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap)